# help for custom spinner?

Tags: android, android-layout

i am getting error while using the custom class for spinner from below link.

[How to make an Android Spinner with initial text "Select One"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one)

can anyone suggest me how can i use it

thankx

Comment: whch class u talking abt?pls specify clearly

Comment: Can you clarify on what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to have first item not being selected automatically, then I have answered that query in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726490/android-set-spinner-default-value-to-null/4727279#4727279) with code snippets.