# Android Spinner Help

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, spinner

I'm making an android application in eclipse, but I got some issues with the spinners. First of all I would like my spinner to start on no target at all. You see when I start the application the spinner already have the first item in my list selected, and I don't like that. My second issue is that I would like to link specific targets on my list to different url website, don't know really how to do that.

something like:

```
if item <item>"xxxx"</item> is selected
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://google.com")));"
```

Answer (score 0):

- First part: No default target in spinner
  You can have an empty string as first element in the Spinner's adapter and take care to ignore that first (0th) index in your implementation.
- Second part: linking URL

  1. You can have a mapping for elements in Spinner's adapter with its respective URL.
  2. In `onItemSelected()` implementation, based on which item is selected, you select the URL from the mapping implementation and load that URL as you need.

For code you can have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726490/android-set-spinner-default-value-to-null/4727279#4727279), its not a complete code as you need above but it can get you started.

Comment: Thx :) But I still don't figure out how to link different elements to different Urls in my spinner. Do you mean "onItemSelected(XXXX) startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://google.com")));""

Comment: You can create a WebView object say myWebView and use loadUrl() method as: myWebView.loadUrl(yourUrlString);