# Default empty spinner

Tags: android, spinner

How I can set spinner empty by default? I mean that spinner doesn't have value (empty value) till user choice it.

Comment: might be this link help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726490/android-set-spinner-default-value-to-null 

let me know in any case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually just provide one fake value with toString empty string. Then the spinner appears empty to the user. Afterwords just perform validation before you finish the activity and if the default value is still on, just show an error, rather than continuing on.