# How to set the selected item color in the spinner?

Tags: android, xml, spinner

```
<Spinner
     android:id="@+id/spinner1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"  
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1F"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtLabel1F" 
     android:entries="@array/cat_array"  
     android:prompt="@string/cat_promt" 
     android:textColor="#ffffff"                            
   />
```

My Background is black and the item showing is with gray bg and black font color. But when it come to the selected it shows the font as black so it is not being seen. How do I change the color in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a custom spinner layout to achieve what you want.

check out these questions, they have the answers you want:

[How to customize a Spinner in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694786/how-to-customize-a-spinner-in-android)

[Android: Custom Spinner Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946893/android-custom-spinner-layout)

The idea is to create a layout for your row, and set it when creating a spinner with its adapter in code.

Comment: I got it with http://adanware.blogspot.in/2012/03/android-custom-spinner-with-custom.html from the link you gave me thank you =D

Answer (score 4):

Simplest use this

use this to change the text of selected Text

```
YOUR_SPINNER.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
     TextView selectedText=  view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name_in_Adapter);
     selectedText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.YOUR_COLOR));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `MaterialBetterSpinner` and Binding your Layouts,
try this, hope it helps you:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {      

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);           

    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final YourXMLBinding rowBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.yourXML, parent,false);
        rowBinding.tv1.setText(mMy.getValues().get(position));
        if(position == mMy.getCurrentIndex()) {
            rowBinding.tv1.setTypeface(Typer.set(getContext()).getFont(Font.ROBOTO_BOLD));//change font
            rowBinding.tv1.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.yourColor));//change color
        }
        return rowBinding.getRoot();
    }
}
```

Your XML should be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/colorBackgroundStart">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

create a spinner with this adapter and yourXML :

```
final MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.yourXML, s.getValues());

final MaterialBetterSpinner spinner = new MaterialBetterSpinner(getContext());
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```