# Android: having error in onItemSelected for Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I getting default value in EditText even i didn't choose from spinner yet.Can anyone help me?

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    etCountry.setText("");
    switch(parent.getId()){
    case R.id.spcountry:
        etCountry.setText(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
        break;
    }

}
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    etCountry.setText("");
}
```

Comment: Here is some good answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726490/android-set-spinner-default-value-to-null

Comment: What you are trying to do with the Switch Case?

Comment: actually i have total 4 Spinner.That y i'm using switch & some us if/else.

Answer (score 0):

**In you code**,

You Setting the edittext value to empty `etCountry.setText("");` here. But you setting the value again in Switch case.

**Switch Case**

```
   case R.id.spcountry:
    etCountry.setText(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());//Here is where you setting the edittext value again
    //Do you stuff here if you dont want default text
    break;
```

**EDIT**

To find Where you set etCountry value. Go to `Find-> or Press Ctl+F`. Enter etCountry search it and you will find where you setting the value.

Hope it hepls.

Comment: I have remove etCountry.setText("") ready but still i'm getting the first value of Spinner.

Comment: Then i think some where you set the etCountry value. Have you set any value in xml