# Having a little issue with an action of my spinner

Tags: java, android, spinner

I wanted to add some actions to my `spinner` (as you can see in my code below, I added some `Toasts`).

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    String[] items = {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        ArrayAdapter AA = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);

        AA.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(AA);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        if (selectedItem.equals("Item 1")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        String selectedItem2 = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        if (selectedItem.equals("Item 2")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        String selectedItem3 = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        if (selectedItem.equals("Item 3")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item 3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        String selectedItem4 = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        if (selectedItem.equals("Item 4")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item 4", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        String selectedItem5 = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        if (selectedItem.equals("Item 5")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item 5", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="89dp"></Spinner>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So, actually this code works fine BUT if I open the app, the first Toast (with the text "Item 1") is already visible. But I don't want that. So, what do I need to do, that this  doesn't happen?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

String[] items = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
boolean app_started = true;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    ArrayAdapter AA = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);

    AA.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(AA);

}

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
  if(!app_started )
{


        if(selectedItem.equals("Item 1")) {         
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        String selectedItem2 = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        if(selectedItem.equals("Item 2")) {         
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        String selectedItem3 = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        if(selectedItem.equals("Item 3")) {         
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item 3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        String selectedItem4 = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        if(selectedItem.equals("Item 4")) {         
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item 4", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        String selectedItem5 = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        if(selectedItem.equals("Item 5")) {         
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item 5", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

 }
   app_started = false;

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent)  {


    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, you meant up vote your answer, ok. ;) Well, I'm sorry but I can't until I have 15 reputations! :(

Comment: check out now ur status

Answer (score 2):

Try this-

```
String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
if(selectedItem.equals("Item 1")) {         
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else if(selectedItem.equals("Item 2")) {         
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else if(selectedItem.equals("Item 3")) {         
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item 3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else if(selectedItem.equals("Item 4")) {         
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item 4", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else if(selectedItem.equals("Item 5")) {         
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item 5", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Also tried your suggestion. It didn't solve my problem but it helped to let my code look better, easier and more understandable! ;) Thanks to you, too! :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, google hasn't provided the feature of having a 'null' value at the start. You can check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726490/android-set-spinner-default-value-to-null) for more details. Hope it helped. :)