# How to prevent the spinner from selecting the first item when user does not select any option?

Tags: android, spinner

When I run the app, it will directly select the first item and then call the intent to `GoogleMap` even if user not yet select any option. How to prevent this? Below are parts of the codes...thank you

## MainActivity.java

```
final ArrayList<Country> countries = new ArrayList<Country>();
countries.add(new Country("Malaysia", R.drawable.malaysia));
countries.add(new Country("Korea", R.drawable.south_korea));
countries.add(new Country("Argentina", R.drawable.argentina));
countries.add(new Country("Australia", R.drawable.australia));
countries.add(new Country("Japan", R.drawable.japan));
countries.add(new Country("United Kingdom", R.drawable.united_kingdom));

customSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.custom_spinner);
SpinnerAdapter adapter = new SpinnerAdapter(this, countries);
customSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
customSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:4.213155, 103.402914"));
                break;
            case 1:
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:36.593562, 127.040436"));
                break;
            case 2:
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:-34.883324, -65.140799"));
                break;
            case 3:
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:-24.372645, 131.823709"));
                break;
            case 4:
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:36.875761, 138.729092"));
                break;
            case 5:
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:54.887410, -2.913750"));
                break;
        }

        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
                startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

## SpinnerAdapter.java

```
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View spinnerItem = convertView;

        if(spinnerItem == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(getContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            spinnerItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_rows, parent, false);
            //spinnerItem = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.spinner_rows, parent, false);
        }

        Country tempCountry = (Country) getItem(position);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) spinnerItem.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView text = (TextView) spinnerItem.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        image.setImageResource(tempCountry.getCountryImage());
        image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        text.setText(tempCountry.getCountryName());

        return spinnerItem;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        return getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }
```

Comment: You may find solution here [How to set spinner value to null initially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726490/how-to-set-spinner-default-value-to-null)

Comment: Check this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13398044/6021469

Comment: just add an empty element or just add "select country"

Comment: @OussemaAroua how to make the "select country" to disappear from the dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add  this to your code

`countries.add(new Country("Select country", -1))`;

add this to your adapter

```
if (tempCountry.getCountryImage() !=  -1 ){
    image.setImageResource(tempCountry.getCountryImage());
    image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}else{
    image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

and your in the case start with `case 1`

Comment: but the "select country" still inside the dropdown list...how to get rid of it?

Comment: you can remove it by `countries.remove(0); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: i tried this method just now and it works! but need to change the null to 0, because the image resource ID is an integer value..thanks

Comment: that true my fault sorry

Comment: actually where to add this: countries.remove(0); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()...i tried to insert but fail too

Comment: you need to insert it at `onItemSelected()` inside `if(position) != 0`, why you want to delete it ? it can stay there with no problems

Comment: I want to delete the "select country" because usually the dropdown wont show the title of the spinner right?

Answer (score 3):

**Please use this code in your MainActivity while setting adapter it will help you.**

```
  SpinnerAdapter adapter = new SpinnerAdapter(this, countries) {

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled(int position) {

            if (position == 0) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;

        }
    };
    customSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
please try below code...

final ArrayList<Country> countries = new ArrayList<Country>();
    countries.add(new Country("Select Country", R.drawable.country_icon));
    countries.add(new Country("Malaysia", R.drawable.malaysia));
    countries.add(new Country("Korea", R.drawable.south_korea));
    countries.add(new Country("Argentina", R.drawable.argentina));
    countries.add(new Country("Australia", R.drawable.australia));
    countries.add(new Country("Japan", R.drawable.japan));
    countries.add(new Country("United Kingdom", R.drawable.united_kingdom));

    customSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.custom_spinner);
    SpinnerAdapter adapter = new SpinnerAdapter(this, countries);
    customSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    customSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                break;
                case 1:
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:4.213155, 103.402914"));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:36.593562, 127.040436"));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:-34.883324, -65.140799"));
                    break;
                case 4:
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:-24.372645, 131.823709"));
                    break;
                case 5:
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:36.875761, 138.729092"));
                    break;
                case 6:
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:54.887410, -2.913750"));
                    break;
            }

            if (position!=0 && intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
                    startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this may be a little late but I have a simple solution which works for me.
I create a switch for any spinner.

So I set a variable
`int spinnerSwitch;`.
Then in `onCreate` I set the switch to `spinnerSwitch = 1;`

Then

```
@Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view
                , int position, long id) {
            String itemText = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Log.i(TAG, "Selected: " + itemText );
            if(spinnerCitySwitch == 1){
                spinnerCitySwitch = 0;
                return;
            }
            //Then you can write your code here
             
        }
```

So when my activity is created, the spinner does automatically select any item in the list. Im sure there are many fancy workarounds out there but this works for me...for now.

Answer (score 0):

In `MainActivity.java` introduce a boolean variable `boolean isFirstTime = true;`
And in the `onItemSelected()` method add this line:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
//If the Spinner's item is selected for the first time then return and make 
//isFirstTime to false, so when the user select it for the second time (as user is 
//always second) the spinner will work fine.
                if(isFirstTime){
                    isFirstTime = false;
                    return;
                }
... }
```

However when the user selects the first option then android does not call onItemSelected() method
So you have to make a custom spinner that will call onItemSelected() even when the item is selected second time

```
public class CustomSpinner extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner {

    private int lastPosition = 0;

//overrite the required constructors
...
//

//In android Spinners, when an item is selected for the second time then android does not call onItemSelected () method
//However, when an item is selected, the setSelection method will always be triggered
// So in this method, we record and check the last selection position. If they are the same, just call the monitor manually
    
@Override
    public void setSelection(int position, boolean animate) {
        super.setSelection(position, animate);
        if (position == lastPosition){
            getOnItemSelectedListener().onItemSelected(this,null,position,0);
        }
        lastPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelection(int position) {
        super.setSelection(position);
        if (position == lastPosition){
            getOnItemSelectedListener().onItemSelected(this,null,position,0);
        }
        lastPosition = position;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the first selection of the list empty.

```
String selecteditem="";
 
if (selecteditem.isEmpty())
{

}else{
    // do work
}
```