# Style button as Spinner

Tags: android

I want that my button looks like a spinner, because I will show a special dialog if the button is clicked. I use `Theme.MaterialComponents` and tried following but it's not working:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btMusclegroups"
            style= "?spinnerStyle"// or style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The button still looks solid and not like a spinner.

**Desired result**

I want that my button looks the same as following `Spinner`:

```
<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/btMusclegroups"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I could use a `Spinner` with  `OnTouchListener` and a dummy adapter (I don't need the adapter, my dialog knows all the data it needs already) but I'd prefer the above way - is this somehow achievable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create an Android Spinner as a popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286847/how-do-i-create-an-android-spinner-as-a-popup)

Comment: No, I'm just talking about the styling. I want a spinner look + a button behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Create a container and add an image view containing the dropdown symbol for the spinner and a button. Add an OnClickListener to the button that calls the dialog and updates the text of the button. Don't forget to style the button as NoBackground.