# Spinners values are not showing in popup box in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to display spinners values in popup box when button clicks. But the spinner values are not showing in popup window.
This is the code in Attach Activity - Button click event:

```
btnimage.setOnClickListener(v->{
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(Attach.this).inflate(R.layout.activity_attach_form,null);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Attach.this);
            builder.setView(view);
            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        });
```

In My attach form activity, am trying to show the spinner values.

```
Spinner spindoc;
String[] doc = {"select", "doc1", "doc2", "doc3"};
spindoc = findViewById(R.id.spindoc);
            spindoc.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            ArrayAdapter adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,doc);
            adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spindoc.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

Respective XML files:

```
<Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spindoc"
            android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
```

Please let me know if I missed any syntax, while displaying spinners in popup. Because in normal view, the above code is working fine...

Comment: see this doc brother [link] [https://material.io/components/menus/android#dropdown-menus]

Comment: ok refer this link surely help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6288030/12543430

Comment: can u upload your code to github, so i can test it in my device also.

Comment: Thanks...I have shared google drive link  - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ONYMCMNtixweHwkI8vB2uBrjhcIb4eWG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: brother can u please share .zip file,because i am unable to extract this rar file

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B-RL74S04_GgdWXSd7CFs1PASGkYKvqU/view?usp=sharing - in this I have write coding in Attach and AttachForm.java files..

Comment: Any luck....@D_K...waiting for your reply..

Comment: try using   android:spinnerMode="dialog" in spinner tag

Comment: Yes I already tried that...both dialog and dropdown...

Comment: remove this             adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
 line and try to run see what will happen and let me know

Comment: I tried removing the same..but still no values display in spinner.

Comment: can u share a video if possible. add this spinnerMode="dialog" and remove that line I told u before and run and share the video brother.

Comment: `<Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spindoc"     android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"     android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />`   and commented the line `ArrayAdapter<String>adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AttachForm.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,doc);
        //adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spindoc.setAdapter(adapter);`