# how to set a title for spinner which is not selectable..?

Tags: android

I have `spinner` but in it only selectable items are shown as default title..

is there any way i can set title which doesn't appear when spinner unfolds...

Comment: please be more specific or an image will be for better for understanding .

Comment: well to precise i need a title to spinner.. which is not selectable but is always visible before selecting anything in spinner... and it should not appear in the list of options selectable,....

Comment: Take a look here:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html Also, you can create a custom dialog that looks identical to a spinner. Then you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just realized what you were trying to do.   You want the Spinner "button" to have a title.  Something like "- Select One -", correct?

If that is indeed the case, here is how I accomplished this.  Don't use a spinner.  Instead, use a button and style with the title to look like a spinner (will have to find how I did this).  When the user clicks the button, open a "select one" dialog and style it to look like a spinner's dialog.  I'll try to put a code sample up shortly.

Comment: tat's a good idea.. i can implement it myself.. thanks..

Comment: @SBerg413, you didn't answered whether we can set tittle which is not selectable?

Comment: re-inventing the wheel to have such a simple thing?

Comment: if you think this elegant solution is "re-inventing the wheel" simply don't use it. ;-)

Comment: not that elegant... and "reinvent the wheel"

Answer (score 58):

You will have to set the **prompt** attribute of spinner.

```
<Spinner   android:id="@+id/discuss_about_spinner"  
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:prompt="@string/discuss_about_header"
           android:layout_below="@+id/what_time_layout">
</Spinner>
```

Programmatically set title to Spinner

```
spinner.setPrompt("Title");
```

I don't know what the reason is, prompt don't support direct substitution of a string value. Instead you must have your string in **strings.xml**.

Comment: This one should be selected as answer, as setting a title in a `Spinner` is already available. Otherwise use `spinner.setPrompt("Title")` method.

Comment: This should not be the selected answer, this isn't what the question is asking. The question is asking to have a spinner hold [1,2,3], but before an option is selected, the spinner itself does not have one of the [1,2,3] values shown. It shows a title such as "Select One"

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid this is not available out-of-the-box. You'll need to implement this yourself.

Comment: i would ve done it.. but don't want to take unnecessary risk if its readily available..:)