# spinner with text at startup or without, dialogalert after choose first element

Tags: android, spinner, android-alertdialog

I'd like to do spinner with no text at startup or it can have text "choose". Morever after choose first element from the list, there should appear dialogalert. And here is my problem: using this method [How to make an Android Spinner with initial text "Select One"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one) alertdialog popup immediately, when spinner isn't clicked (because first item is always chosen). I'm open for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the behavior your looking to create is fairly complex and beyond the standard capabilities of a Spinner.  I would suggest creating a new Activity for this.  Then you can easily control the UI as needed.

You can use [Activity.startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) to return a value from one Activity to another.