# Android: How to get unselectable item in spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

i want one item in spinner , which discribes for what this spinner is and also i want it to be unSelectable can any budy know how to do this with sample example .
 For Example 
 first item as selectone and it is unselectable and items to be selected

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `android:prompt="Select Question"` for Spinner.

Comment: i done this but i want first item as select and it is unselectable

Answer (score 0):

you will get your answer on following link

[How to make an Android Spinner with initial text "Select One"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one)

however you have to get subclass of spinner in which you need to maintain 2 adapter internally. One adapter that has the "your description" option, and the other real adapter (with the actual options)