# how to make spinner without title(value selected) shown

Tags: android, spinner

i'm trying to make a spinner with just arrow but without title, which looks like google maps using to get user's origin or destination for directions
[image]

and after you click on the arrow(triangle), start a new map as background.
i have searched for quite a time, found most relate topic are about remove that arrow with a new background , or how to set the prompt/hint/text before selecting any items in the list.so far i got no luck
is that really a spinner? or just a button+popwindow ？or it's related to the adapter?
 thank you very much ...

by

```
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View empty = inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty, parent, false);
        return empty;
```

in getView of class that extends ArrayAdapter, now there is
[image]

what ever which item is selected,but how to remove the underline and the space it takes, change background?

Comment: Try putting an empty string as the first element in the array associated with the adapter

Comment: thanks codeMagic , but the tricky point is, what ever you select, spinner just don't show anything, but change text of the nearby EditText, as google map app do. is there a way that we can change all select item to empty string but still show some label ? thanks

Comment: I don't know of any way to do that. I think the easiest way, that I know of without overriding native methods, is to use a a `TextView` and `ImageButton` and make them clickable. Then you can set the text to whatever you want and use an `onClick()` to perform the actions

Comment: hi codeMagic, i extends ArrayAdapter class and override getView to show nothing during and after selection, now the problem is there any way to just get rid of the underline but leave the arrow?changing background? Using ImageButton is a sure solution, thanks

Comment: Not that I know of that's why I suggested using a `TextView` there instead of `Spinner`

Comment: You can see if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483883/spinner-with-empty-selection) is what you want

Comment: i used android:layout_width="wrap_content" ,it's a dirty but simplest solution. thank you codeMagic

Comment: yes! that exactly the same problem, and solution is alike. it really helps,thank you codeMagic

Answer (score 0):

another solution is as @codeMagic said, with a image button and on click method. and by the way i found

```
        <EditText
    android:id="@+id/date"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

as mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170289/show-custom-dialog-when-spinner-is-being-clicked/12632633#12632633)
and look like

[image]

a little weird.