# How to set default value of spinner

Tags: kotlin, android-spinner

I have a spinner to Change font size of TextView, I use background for the spinner as shown in first picture. I have two problems, First: when I run the app the spinner looks like the second picture I don't want to show word "Small" or any selection in the Spinner background..
Second problem: I want to set medium as default value. how can I do this?

[image]

[image]

**Here is my spinner code**

```
val fontSize = arrayOf("Small", "Medium", "Large")
    spinner.adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, fontSize)
    spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
        }

        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
            when (position) {
                1 -> R.dimen.txt_size_small
                0 -> R.dimen.txt_size_normal
                2 -> R.dimen.txt_size_large
                else -> null
            }?.let {
                textView.textSize = resources.getDimension(it)
            }
        }
    }
```

**xml code**

```
<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/font_size">
    </Spinner>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483883/spinner-with-empty-default-selected-item