# Spinner original text

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm trying my Spinner to display "Select City" before the Spinner has itself been clicked by the user.

How can I do this?

My current XML code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.olacabs.customer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/page_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:text="@string/rate_card"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    custom:customFont="litera_bold.ttf" />

 <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/select_city"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:prompt="@string/selectCity" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Also, what does `android:spinnerMode` exactly do. I tried changing its value to `dropdown` but nothing happened and the application still showed a popup dialogue.

My activity that implements this XML file is:

```
public class RateCardActivity extends OlaActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.rate_card);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.select_city);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.select_city, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item); 
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you need to set the theme to Holo

Comment: check this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867039/set-text-of-spinner-before-item-is-selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this .. Create a custom adapter to insert..

Try the following code

In your resources

```
<string-array name="listarray">
<item>Select One</item>
<item>Item One</item>
<item>Item Two</item>
<item>Item Three</item>
</string-array>
```

In your onItemSelected Listener:

```
TextView selection;
spinnername.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
selection.setText("");
}
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    if (pos == 0) {
    }else {
        // Your code to process the selection
    }
}
});
```

For more info go through this [Link](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1517) & [Link](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/)

Comment: I'm guessing that the default Spinner text should be declared in the `onNothingSelected` method. What should the code be in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

CHange :
`extends OlaActivity`   to `extends Activity`