# Android custom spinner (NoDefaultSpinner) prompt cutoff from view

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner, prompt

I have implemented a custom spinner where no initial default selection is made. The code for NoDefaultSpinner is from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/3427058/1257074

The problem is that the Prompt defined for this spinner in the xml layout file, is cuttoff if the Layout Width = wrap_content is less than the width of the Prompt text. See below.

[image: NoDefaultSpinner cutoff]

One solution is to just define a width in the xml file for the custom spinner, but unfortunately the spinner is generated dynamically in code.

Any ideas or suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just ended up dynamically changing the width:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) s1.getLayoutParams();
lp.width = 400;
s1.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try overriding [onMeasure(int,int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure%28int,%20int%29) in the spinner with a special case "if nothing is selected" that size it correctly.

It's more or less what is done when inflating the xml.

Comment: Could you give an example of such an implementation?

Comment: You can find some on android website [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) and with LabelView class (in the API sample code)