# Android spinner adapter setDropDownViewResource custom layout with radiobutton

Tags: android-widget, android

I use Spinner in Dialog Mode.
I set SimpleCursorAdapter for the Spinner with setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
That works fine.

Now instead of simple_spinner_dropdown_item I'm trying to pass my custom layout it does work well too.

But there is a but... it does not have radio button that original simple_spinner_dropdown_item does.
Is it possible to add radio button inside of my custom spinner_dropdown_item that would be selected when spinner dialog is shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have found solution. ListView (what is inside of the spinners dialog) will check if your View is Checkable and call setChecked. Since android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item is checkable it works.
So for my custom List item i have created LinearLayout that implements Checkable

```
public class CheckableLinearLayout extends LinearLayout implements Checkable
{
private boolean _isChecked = false;

public CheckableLinearLayout(Context context)
    {
    super(context);
    }

public CheckableLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
    super(context, attrs);
    }

@Override
public void setChecked(boolean checked)
    {
    _isChecked = checked;

    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++)
        {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof Checkable)
            {
            ((Checkable) child).setChecked(_isChecked);
            }
        }
    }

@Override
public boolean isChecked()
    {
    return _isChecked;
    }

@Override
public void toggle()
    {
    _isChecked = !_isChecked;
    }

}
```

So ListView calls setChecked and I propagate that down to children views and my CheckBox / RadioButton will get checked / unchecked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

yes its possible but you have to define a another class for spinner.Just look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one)

you have one more option to get your requirement. that is `Alert dialog`

just check out this [Alert Dialog Window with radio buttons in Android](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/alert-dialog-window-with-radio-buttons-in-android/) and [How to create custom and drop down type dialog and Dialog in android](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/07/how-to-create-custom-and-default-alert.html)