# how to remove first item from spinner

Tags: android

whenever i create a spinner by default it shows first element in spinner. i want to show my own hint on that spinner.

**note:- i am receiving data from web services.**

Xml

```
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerAtlasContactSignup"
            android:layout_width="200dip"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editCompanySignup"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/slect_box1x"
            android:ems="10"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:prompt="@string/atlas_contact" />
```

Code -

```
private void initializeSpinner(ArrayList<AtlasContact> atlastContacts) {

ArrayAdapter<AtlasContact> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<AtlasContact>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, atlastContacts);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
spinnerAtlasContact.setAdapter(adapter);
```

here `AtlasContact` is a class which accepts the data coming from web services.

Comment: @ChiragRaval `AtlastContacts` is object :)

Comment: put your first item empty in string  array:p

Comment: @ TechEnd: sorry for asking silly que bt hw to do that.???

Comment: go to the string array or wherever the spinner gets the information and put the first item as empty string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an Android Spinner with initial text "Select One"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below one

```
    private void initializeSpinner(ArrayList<AtlasContact> atlastContacts) {

    ArrayList<AtlasContact> atlastContactsDuplicate ; 
    For (int i= 0 ; i < atlastContacts+1 ; i++){
     if (i==0){
           atlastContactsDuplicate.add("") ; //this is null object which can be 
                                             //adjust           weight space     
        }
    else
    atlastContactsDuplicate.add(atlastContacts.get(i)) ; 
    }
        ArrayAdapter<AtlasContact> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<AtlasContact>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, atlastContactsDuplicate);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinnerAtlasContact.setAdapter(adapter); 
}
```

Comment: sorry man but m gettin two errors 1.The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) ArrayList<AtlasContact>, int. 2.The method add(AtlasContact) in the type ArrayList<AtlasContact> is not applicable for the arguments (String). please help

Comment: i have made a comment at atlastContactsDuplicate.add("") ; 
, you can not pass it as string of-course , pass blank value of AtlasContact class

Answer (score 1):

get all data using for loop and in this for loop create new arraylist and when i=0
 so not add array list data and set new array list in spinner

Answer (score 0):

Change your `initializeSpinner()` to add your object at the '0' th index -

```
 private void initializeSpinner(ArrayList<AtlasContact> atlastContacts) {

atlastContacts.add(0, new AtlasContact()); //Set the properties of the anonymous object to what you want.

    ArrayAdapter<AtlasContact> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<AtlasContact>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, atlastContacts);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinnerAtlasContact.setAdapter(adapter); 
    }
```