# Show triangle inside the view that opens a popupmenu (like with a spinner)

Tags: android, menu, spinner, popupmenu

I have a `ListView` which handles onClick events by showing a `PopUpMenu`. However, I want the user to see the little triangle inside the views that can be clicked.

I tried using a `Spinner`, because that element looks like what I'm after, but I can't set the title of the `Spinner` to anything other than its options.

Of course I could custom make everything but as this is not a new pattern I thought maybe there's already something out there. I just can't find it myself.

Example of what I'm after:

[image: spinner example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `ActionBarSherlock`, you can use the triangle ABS uses:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        etc />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/expand_triangle"
        android:src="@drawable/abs__spinner_ab_default_holo_light" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for the [prompt attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#attr_android%3aprompt) that you can set for a spinner?

Beyond that, I would suggest using the [SlideExpandableListView](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/12/slide-expandable-listview/) if you haven't already invested too much time in your current implementation and if that is the pattern that you would like to achieve:

> This library allows you to have custom listview in which each list item
>   has an area that will slide-out once the users clicks on a certain
>   button.

Comment: I was actually looking for something that does a `PopUpMenu`, but this looks pretty sweet as well. Thanks!

Comment: As far as the prompt text goes, I think they dropped it since Honeycomb: `The prompt to display when the spinner's dialog is shown.` It doesn't show up in my tests either.

Comment: Ok, didn't know it was for the dialog only, sorry for the confusion. Nevertheless, there are some more approaches here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one