# How do I show the default triangle of a custom spinner object?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-spinner

By default, whenever you populate your spinner with an array via an adapter, there is a little triangle in the bottom right corner of the spinner object.  I decided to make a custom spinneritem and spinner item drop list, however, when I did I lost the simple but effective triangle.  This question, [Show triangle inside the view that opens a popupmenu (like with a spinner)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306923/show-triangle-inside-the-view-that-opens-a-popupmenu-like-with-a-spinner), did not answer my question and is the only source I have been able to be remotely close to answering my question.  I made a TextView xml file for the spinner item called spinner_item.xml and another xml file that used another TextView for my dropdown list.  Here is the code for each xml file:

spinner_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:background="#ff6600"    
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#355e3b"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        />
```

spinner_dropdown_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:background="#ff6600"
    android:textColor="#355e3b"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    />
```

The source that I used to get this code was found here: http://www.broculos.net/2013/09/how-to-change-spinner-text-size-color.html#.U74fHFFWNq0

I didn't post the code from the MainActivity class as the code I currently have compiles and runs fine.  I just want to see the triangle so the user knows to select that list.  Thanks for any help!