# Adding default None value to a spinner from DB cursor

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner which is populated with DB values returned in form of Cursor.but it always have first value as selected. What I need is to have a "None" value instead od ffirst DB value. I know we can do this when we have hardcoded strings but how can i do it with Cursor..??

My code for spinner -

```
Cursor c = listNamesDbHelper.fetchAllUserLists();
        startManagingCursor(c);
        Log.i(TAG, "cursor list names--->>" + c.getCount());
        // create an array to specify which fields we want to display
        String[] from = new String[c.getCount() + 1];
        from = new String[]{listNamesDbHelper.KEY_LIST_NAME};

        //from[0] = "None";
        // create an array of the display item we want to bind our data to
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.ModifyTaskListNameItem};

        // create simple cursor adapter
        /*SimpleCursorAdapter adapter =
          new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.choose_list_modify_task, c, from, to );
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );*/
        // get reference to our spinner

        CustomSpinnerItemsAdapter adapter = new CustomSpinnerItemsAdapter(this,c,from,to);
        Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById( R.id.spinnerListSelection );
        s.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Thanks in advance,
Ray

Comment: i think that you can't have a none value unless you hardcoded none string in your spinner

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one) might help.