# How to set a default text to a Spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I want to set the spinner to show the name country even if any other list is selected. I have used a textview which displays the selected item of the Spinner List. As I used the setselection method to set the spinner title to Country the EditText also eventually changes. I went through various topic answered regarding this but couldn't find suitable response

I am attaching my code below

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.spinner;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Spinner sp;
    TextView t;
    String[] country;
    int sp_position;
    String selected;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String myString = "Country"; 

        sp = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        country = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,country);   
        sp_position = ad.getPosition(myString);
        sp.setAdapter(ad);
        ad.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                selected = sp.getSelectedItem().toString();
                System.out.println(selected);
                setid();

            }

            private void setid() {
                sp.setSelection(sp_position);


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        t.setText(selected);

    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

My XML file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:hint="Address" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="72dp" 
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My STRINGS.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Spinner</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string-array name="spinner">
        <item>Country</item>
        <item>India</item>
        <item>Russia</item>
        <item>USA</item>
        <item>France</item>
        <item>United Kingdom</item>
    </string-array>
<string name ="Country">Country</string>
</resources>
```

My Requirement is whatever is selected in the spinner the Textview should display the selected Item but The spinner should always show the first item or in my case Country

Comment: What do you want exactly? Give an example.

Comment: Say there is a Spinner which contains the list of countries and a textview. Initially the spinner has a header named Country and after selecting the list in the spinner the Textview should get the value of the item selected on the spinner but the spinner should still display its default title i.e Country

Comment: Ok got it, You want this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one

Comment: Also go through this http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/

Comment: No this example shows another drop down list nested in one. My question is after selecting a value in the spinner the selected value should be displayed in Textview and the spinner should set to initial value

Comment: Here's a really [simple solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21734833/2402866) for adding default text to your spinner.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use this code

declaration

```
String selected, spinner_item;
```

spinner code

```
sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            selected = sp.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (!selected.equals("Country"))
                spinner_item = selected;
            System.out.println(selected);

            setid();
        }

        private void setid() {
            sp.setSelection(sp_position);
            t.setText(spinner_item);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: If i remove the sp.setSelection(sp_position) the spinner shows the value which is selected

Comment: @Saras as per this..My Requirement is whatever is selected in the spinner the Textview should display the selected Item but The spinner should always show the first item or in my case Country..you have to display selected itemm

Comment: My problem is once i select the value from the spinner the Textview shows the spinner for few seconds and when the Spinner gets to it default setselection value the Text view shows the default value again.


I want the Textview to show the value which is selected from the spinner and not change back to default value of the Spinner

Comment: See my edited answer it's working fine. use this code. if you have any doubts let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Reddy. It works Exactly as i Want. Thanks a lot

Comment: can i automatically assign a specific item to my spinner?

Comment: @Sunny Yes, you can spinner.setSelection( item position ). 
 Ex: spinner.setSelection(0).

Answer (score 10):

```
spinner.setPrompt("Pick One");
```

Comment: This only works when you set `android:spinnerMode‌​="dialog"` to your spinner

Answer (score 5):

You only need 3 lines of code for this:

(1) Declare a global variable that is used to save and load the spinner item ID. By global, I mean declaring it right after "public class MainActivity extends Activity {".

```
int mySpinner_selectedId;
```

(2) Then, add the following code AFTER the user has made his/her choice. One good location would be a button that appears together with your spinner.

```
mySpinner_selectedId = mySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

(3) Finally, add the following code right after "mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);" to load the last selected item.

```
mySpinner.setSelection(mySpinner_selectedId);
```

You're most welcomed.

Answer (score 3):

Use `android:prompt="@string/select"` in spinner....

Comment: How to display popup ?

Comment: This only works when you set `android:spinnerMode="dialog"` to your spinner

Answer (score 2):

Do it this way.
After setting the textView setSelection to 0th position of your spinner list

```
sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
        int arg2, long arg3) {

        selected = sp.getSelectedItem().toString();
        System.out.println(selected);
        t.setText(selected);
        sp.setSelection(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: No after selecting the list it shows the value in Textview for a few seconds and when the Spinner gets to 0th position the Textview gets its value..

Comment: what if i want to automatically set a specif item/value in my spinner??

Answer (score 1):

Try this way.

```
sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3) {
        //selected = sp.getSelectedItem().toString();
        //System.out.println(selected);
        if(arg2!=0)
           t.setText(sp.getSelectedItem().toString());
        sp.setSelection(0);
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you. Let me know what happens. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
        int pos, long id) {

           spinner.setSelection(pos);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Countryspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            if (position == 0) {
                txtSpinner1.setHint("Select Country");
            } else {
                txtSpinner1.setText(CountryList.get(position));
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            txtSpinner1.setHint("Select Country");
        }

    });
```

Comment: here i generated the spinner and textview programatically.. you can use set text instead of sethint

Answer (score 0):

In `onItemSelected` method add this code `sp.setSelection(0);`

Comment: No Jyoti the Textview displays the value selected for a few seconds. And when the Spinner is made to set to its initial value the Textview is also set to its initial value

Comment: paste this inside the method of onItemSelected

Answer (score 0):

**I done this in a simple way**

1. > Add **default text at adapter first or end position**(in my case end ) and **set this item as default selection**. ---- Also get default selection position, So that no action will perform in setOnItemSelectedListener().

   ```
   taskName.add("one");
   taskName.add("two");
   taskName.add("select a task");
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, taskName);
   binding.spnTask.setAdapter(adapter);
   binding.spnTask.setSelection(adapter.getPosition("select a task name"));
   final int defaultPosition = binding.spnTask.getSelectedItemPosition();
   ```
2. > Check selected position is default text position

   ```
     binding.spnTask.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

           if (position == defaultPosition) {
               Toast.makeText(this, "No Action", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }else{  Toast.makeText(this, "Your Action" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   }
       }

       @Override
       public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

       }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        mySpinner.setPrompt("Categorie");
        final ArrayList<String> strDeviceArr = new ArrayList<>();

        mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String valueSelected = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if(!valueSelected.equals("Categorie"))
                    Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this, ""+valueSelected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```