# Android Set xml value with string

Tags: android, xml

I have this following spinner in my main activity
My problem is that the spinner's value is required when submitting but i want its default value to be empty so i put in my arrays.xml an item with empty value. so when the app is lunched it will show a empty spinner.
The problem is that when they click the spinner and the drop down display the first selection is empty.

[image]

my solution is to put the first data as "Select" but is there a way that the value would be empty like in html select tag?

```
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="data 1">data 1</option>
```

on android xml is this possible? or how to do it? i tried this but still not working. it passes the value "Select"

```
   <item value="">Select</item>
   <item value="data 1">data 1</item>
```

---

my spinner

```
<Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:entries="@array/spinner_arr"
                android:tag="relation" />
```

my arrays.xml

```
<string-array name="spinner_arr">
    <item></item>
    <item>data 1</item>
    <item>data 2</item>
    <item>data 3</item>
    <item>data 4</item>
    <item>data 5</item> 
</string-array>
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19945860/849939

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `prompt` attr of Spinner, if that's not work you'll have to craete some adapter of your own.
take a look here:
[How to make an Android Spinner with initial text "Select One"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one)