# How to set tittle for spinner in android

Tags: android

For spinner how to set tittle ,i tried with 'prompt' in both xml and activity file ,it is showing as tittle for dropdown list after clicking on spinner but i want to give tittle for spinner how to do it,help me.

```
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setPrompt(getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world));
```

Comment: you want the spinner button to have title?

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3427058/1405983

Comment: @Prince hey i already seen just for tittle that much code??give me any short answer,if it is final answer i will stop using spinner.

Comment: Here is the perfect solution and it's working in my case.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

> spinner.setPrompt("Select Things");

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a Button instead. While a Button is not a Spinner, the behavior is easy to customize.

First create the Adapter as usual:

```
String[] items = new String[] {"One", "Two", "Three"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
```

Note that I am using the simple_spinner_dropdown_item as the layout id. This will help create a better look when creating the alert dialog.

In the onClick handler for my Button I have:

```
public void onClick(View w) {
  new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
  .setTitle("the prompt")
  .setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

      // TODO: user specific action

      dialog.dismiss();
    }
  }).create().show();
}
```

And that's it!

Answer (score 0):

use that

```
 <Spinner
              android:id="@+id/spinner3"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:entries="@array/gender"
            android:prompt="@string/Gender_prompt1" 
               />
```

and string.xml

```
<string name="Gender_prompt1">Choose a Gender</string>
```