# Set the default Text into spinner programmatically

Tags: android

I have a spinner like this:

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(context);
spinner.setPadding(0, 10, 10, 0);
ArrayAdapter<ItemValue> aa = new ArrayAdapter<ItemValue>(context,
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,elemItemSet);
aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(aa);
```

Now I need a add a default/initial text programmatically (without using xml) & without adding into list 'elemItemSet'.

Is it possible?

Comment: i think you are looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one

Comment: ur question is not clear ..wat do u want

Comment: @Shakeeb I need to display a default text like 'Select' but it must not be a option.

Comment: ok I got it ..I think link added by  BBdev answers ur problem

Answer (score 0):

To show defualt value(Select) at spinner,you have to add "Select" text into your array list at  O index. And apply condition like "When the value of spinner is 'select' then show message to user like 'Select any value'".

I hope it will help you.

Thnaks