# Using a variable to switch to a certain spinner item

Tags: android, switch-statement, spinner

I have:

- a String array with an unknown length that's populated with unknown items (let's say fish, bird, cat)
- an ArrayAdapter and a Spinner that displays the items
- a variable that contains one unknown item from the string array (let's say cat)

I want to set the Spinner to the value from the variable (cat). What's the most elegant solution? I thought about running the string through a loop and comparing the items with the variable (until I hit cat in this example), then use that iteration's # to set the selection of the Spinner, but that seems very convoluted.

Or should I just ditch the Spinner? I looked around and found a solution that uses a button and dialog field: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5790662/1928813

**//EDIT: My current code. I want to use "cow" without having to go through the loop, if possible!**

```
        final Spinner bSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    String[] animals = new String[] { "cat", "bird", "cow", "dog" };
    String animal = "cow";
    int spinnerpos;
    final ArrayAdapter<String> animaladapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, animals);
    animaladapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    bSpinner.setAdapter(animaladapter);

    for (Integer j = 0; j < animals.length; j++) {
        if (animals[j].equals(animal)) {
            spinnerpos = j;
            bSpinner.setSelection(spinnerpos);
        } else {
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Temporarily) convert your String array to a `List` so you can use `indexOf`.

```
int position = Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(randomVariable);
spinner.setSelection(position);
```

**EDIT:**

I understand your problem now. If your String array contains all unique values, you can put them in a HashMap for O(1) retrieval:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
   map.put(animals[i], i);
} 

String randomAnimal = "cow";
Integer position = map.get(randomAnimal);

if (position != null) bSpinner.setSelection(position);
```

Comment: That's not really what I'm asking for.. I added my code, should clarify it a bit I guess.

Comment: Great. Thanks! "position" has to be defined as Integer (not int), in case someone else uses this and gets an error :)