# Android spinner prompt

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a problem with `android:prompt` for a spinner. I used this code in the XML file but it doesn't work:

```
<Spinner 
    android:id="@+id/spinner" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:prompt="@string/club_type">
</Spinner>
```

I also tried to use this code in my main activity but this doesn't work either:

```
spinner.setPrompt("Select club");
```

While I was using the second case I didn't use `android:prompt`; in other words, I tried them individually. Could someone help me?

Comment: Dublicate question[WATCH THIS][1]
Try it, hope it will helpet you

  


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one/12221309#12221309

Comment: prompt only showed up on dialog mode and spinner's default mode is dropdown  in order to change the mode use android:spinnerMode="dialog"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Working perfectly on mine.

You are mistaking **prompt** with first element. Tap on the spinner and you will see `Select club` as the heading which is the prompt.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're right! My code show prompt in the Dialog Mode, I saw only drop down. So, how can I show "select club" like first element but it can't be selected?

Comment: I think you will need to put "select club" as the first element. If you can't do it, you can always ask new questions. Best of luck Breaking Bad

Comment: Ok, I'll try some code and then I'll ask. Thank you very much! ahaha ;)

Answer (score 20):

There are two ways you can deal with that:

**Static way:**

add one line code in XML's Spinner tag

```
android:spinnerMode="dialog"
```

and then set:

```
android:prompt="PROMPT"
```

**In dynamic way:**

use

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnner); 
String[] myItems= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spinner1);
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, 
android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, myItems);

spinner.setPrompt("PROMPT");
```

when you set and initialize your adapter

hope that can help you! :)