# How to create alertdialog in spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-alertdialog

I want to create alertDialog in spinner selected item, and add an EditText inside of alertDialog. 
Thanks

```
        sh = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.shield);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adaptera = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
            R.array.shield, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adaptera.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sh.setAdapter(adaptera);



    sh.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            sa = (String) sh.getSelectedItem();
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuildera = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            alertDialogBuildera.setTitle("Your Title");
            alertDialogBuildera
                    .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            double sl = Double.valueOf(tc.getText().toString());
                                            getActivity().finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alertDialoga = alertDialogBuildera.create();
            if (sa.trim().equals("Lead")) {
                alertDialoga.show();
            } else
            if (sa.trim().equals("Steel")) {
                alertDialoga.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

it's doesn't work. 
if I selected item, the alertdialog automaticaly shown.

Comment: More explain your question with code.

Comment: alert dialog in spinner? or on item selection in spinner?

Comment: on item selection in spinner.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below link.This will gives you detailed explanation on how to customize spinner. hope this will solves your problem.

http://mrbool.com/how-to-customize-spinner-in-android/28286

In that example you should replace imageview with edittext

Please use the below code i replaced imageview with edittext its working fine

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Spinner Customization"
        android:textSize="30px" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_show"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100px"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />
```

**custom_spinner.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="3px" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/left_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80px" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_main_seen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
        android:layout_marginTop="2px"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left_content"
        android:padding="3px"
        android:text="JMD Group"
        android:textColor="#0022ee"
        android:textSize="22px"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sub_text_seen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_main_seen"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left_content"
        android:padding="2px"
        android:text="beyond the expectations..."
        android:textColor="#777777" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String[] spinnerValues = { "Blur", "NFS", "Burnout", "GTA IV", "Racing", };
    String[] spinnerSubs = { "Ultimate Game", "Need for Speed",
            "Ulimate Racing", "Rockstar Games", "Thunder Bolt" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_show);
        mySpinner.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_spinner,
                spinnerValues));
    }

    public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        public MyAdapter(Context ctx, int txtViewResourceId, String[] objects) {
            super(ctx, txtViewResourceId, objects);
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View cnvtView, ViewGroup prnt) {
            return getCustomView(position, cnvtView, prnt);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int pos, View cnvtView, ViewGroup prnt) {
            return getCustomView(pos, cnvtView, prnt);
        }

        public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View mySpinner = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner, parent,
                    false);
            TextView main_text = (TextView) mySpinner
                    .findViewById(R.id.text_main_seen);
            main_text.setText(spinnerValues[position]);
            TextView subSpinner = (TextView) mySpinner
                    .findViewById(R.id.sub_text_seen);
            subSpinner.setText(spinnerSubs[position]);
            EditText left_content = (EditText) mySpinner
                    .findViewById(R.id.left_content);
            left_content.setHint("This is EditText:"+(position+1));
            return mySpinner;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: thanks for the answer, why the EditText can't be write inside on spinner. ex: if i pick one (GTA IV)

Comment: Hope the below link will helps you on what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one