# How to Display Title On Spinner Which Is Not Selectable

Tags: android, android-spinner

i m working on Spinner and i have to display Title which is not selectable. .i have set prompt.
i can not add items on spinner because all the items in spinner is coming from webservice.

Comment: This question is answered well with full code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one

Answer (score 0):

use textview to show title. and on textview click open a dialog and fill your data in array adapter.