# Change spinner icon and list open style

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, spinner, android-spinner

for now radio button image on shown on right side of my spinnerand when I click on it, it open option list in popup box

what I want is to show arrow on right side of spinner and options list should be drop down instead of popup box with white background.

see image

[image]

How Can I do this, Do I need to create a custom spinner?

Here is the code

XML

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/type_spinner"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/text_color"/>
```

Java

```
type_Spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.type_spinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, new String[]{"Buy","Sale","Rent","Let"});
type_Spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

**1st approach**

Change `Spinner` in xml like this

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/type_spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown" />
```

Change `theme` of that `Activity` to

```
android:Theme.Holo
```

In java class

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, new String[]{"Buy","Sale","Rent","Let"});
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
type_Spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**2nd approach**

Instead of `Spinner` use a `Button` set background using `android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"`  [set `gravity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html) (**not layout_gravity**) to `left|center_vertical` open a [`PopupWindow`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) on clicking of that `Button` set that Button as anchor of that PopUpWindow. In that `PopUpWindow` place a `ListView` and in `OnItemClick` change text with **selected value** in that Button using [setText(java.lang.CharSequence)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence))

[Full code snippet for 2nd approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27199251/how-to-add-default-text-in-spinner/27200632#27200632)

> If you use approach 1 then it will work on **Post Gingerbread**
>   version. Approach 2 will work on any version of android(not tested in
>   pre froyo).

Answer (score 1):

In layout use the `android:spinnerMode`

```
android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
```

In activity use like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, new String[]{"Buy","Sale","Rent","Let"});
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
type_Spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```