# how to remove Select Item from Custom Spinner in android

Tags: android

[image]

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
String[] DayOfWeek = { "Select Item", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    mySpinner.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,
            R.layout.row, DayOfWeek));
}

public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.weekofday);
        label.setText(DayOfWeek[position]);

        ImageView icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        if (DayOfWeek[position] == "Sunday") {
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
        } else {
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icongray);
        }

        return row;
    }
}
```

}

here is my code i am able to display value in spinner but i want display Select item only on Textview not in Value while its displaying in value also tell me how to remove that please see screen and tell me how to remove that

Comment: AFAIK this is not the way the Android `Spinner` works: it displays only values, not a title. So just use values and remove that "Select item".

Comment: As @shkschneider stated this is not how the spinner works:
Add a textView above the spinner and remove the "Select item" from the spinner-data

Comment: Use spinner.setPrompt("Select Item"); and remove this "Select Item" string from DayOfWeek array.

Comment: i have tried but its not working

Comment: @Edge Really?.. Show us the updated code then

Comment: Have you tried implementing a base adapter and overriding getDropDownView?

Comment: i dont know how to use custom Spiner please help me how to do that

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is:
a) Modify the array to

```
String[] DayOfWeek = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" };
```

b) Call mySpinner.setPromptId() and set a string reosurceId with value "Select item".

For having the "Select item" only when the drop-down is not opened or closed , follow this link [How to make an Android Spinner with initial text "Select One"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one)?

Comment: where i will set this mySpinner.setPromptId() ?

Comment: @
thepace please check its

Comment: In onCreate() after mySpinner has been intialized.

Comment: but in this case default select item also disappear while i want display it by default

Comment: its currently spinner default set 1

Comment: Try Overriding onNothingSelected to set the promptId again. Do you want to display Select Item only when the dropdown list is not clicked. Right?

Comment: please give me function for that

Answer (score 0):

```
ListPopupWindow numberList;
TextView spDays;
ArrayList<Map<String, String>>() listTrans;

in oncreate spDays.setonclicklistner(this);spDays.setText("Select");
setNumberListSpinnerView();
in onclick(){
  when spDays clicked :- numberList.show();
}


void setNumberListSpinnerView() {

    numberList= new ListPopupWindow(this);
    numberList.setAnchorView(spDays);

    numberList.setOnItemClickListener((new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        getListItem();
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Map map = listTrans.get(position);
            spDays.setText(map.get("circle_name").toString());
            circle_name = map.get("circle_name") + "";
            circle_id = map.get("circle_id").toString();
            circleList.dismiss();
            Log.d("Circle id:", circle_id + "");
            getRetails();

        }
    }));
}


void getListItem(){
    String[] numbers = {"1","2","3","4","5","6"};
    listTrans = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> tran = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    for (String number : numbers) {
        tran.put("numbers", number);
        listTrans.add(tran);
    }
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(AddRetailSurvey.this, listTrans,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            new String[]{"numbers"},
            new int[]{android.R.id.text1});
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    numberList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Change the code with your requirement, check and let me know if you face any problem. The best part of this technique you can change the text color. Thanks :)