# Get the respective value from the array according to selected item position

Tags: android, arrays, android-spinner

I have a spinner and I'm getting its selected item position by  `MyOnItemSelectedListener`. By the time I'm using an array adapter to load items to the spinner. I have loaded the items and it works perfectly. But I have a small problem. When I doesn't select a value then it shows position 0 but it has got the value of 1st array value. As shown in the below image,

[image]

What I want to do is when I haven't select a value then it should get any value from array. And when I select 1st item then only it should get 1st array value.
Array is a created from json response so it is not possible to add a item to array manually.

I have used [How to make an Android Spinner with initial text "Select One"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one) (aaronvargas's answer) to add slect option to spinner as 1st selection.

How can I achieve this? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The first value in the array is at index position `0`. I'm note quite sure where your problem is ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the logic like :

```
int selectedValue = -1;    
if(position<=0){
    //Means Item not selected
}else{
    selectedValue = array[position-1];
}
```

Comment: why u have used int selectedValue = -1;

Comment: @modabeckham just initialised variable. Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something like I have shown.

```
 if(position==0){
        variable = 0;
    }else{
    //use ur logic here
    }
```

Comment: This is sort of working, do I need to use position - 1