# How to set default value to spinner dropdown in Android?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I need to set the default value text **"select your Device"** value to my spinner drop-down list, I put it as list item so it acts as a drop-down list items and I hide the drop-down list, because of that I’m getting a blank space in my drop-down.

How should I do this?

[image]

this is the code I’m used

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        /*Setup a Spinner*/
        mToolbarSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_toolbar);

        /*Manage the spinner*/
        mToolbarSpinnerNavigationItems = new ArrayList<SpinnerNavItem>();

        mToolbarSpinnerNavigationItems.add(new SpinnerNavItem("Select your Seebo", R.drawable.deviceonline));

        /*setting the mToolbarSpinnerNavigationItems to list_item_title_navigation.xml*/
        mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item_title_navigation,mToolbarSpinnerNavigationItems){
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                // remember to inflate custom layout for spinner item
                // then set anything you want here
                // remember to use convertView.findViewById(), not just findViewById()

                // this is an example
                // inflate layout
                convertView = View.inflate(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_item_title_navigation, null);
                // get view
                TextView tvText1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.devicetitle);
                ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deviceicon);
                imgIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //imgIcon.setImageResource(mToolbarSpinnerNavigationItems.get(position).getIcon());
                // set content
                tvText1.setText(mToolbarSpinnerNavigationItems.get(position).getTitle());
                // return
                return convertView;
            }

            @Override
            public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                return convertView;
            }

        };

        //setting adapter to Spinner
        mToolbarSpinner.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make an Android Spinner with initial text "Select One"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one)

Comment: check [this updated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31987339/2826147) answer below

Answer (score 14):

As far as my understanding of your question, what you can do is ***override the `Spinner` `view`*** by getting it **start its indexing from -1 instead of 0** so that making the first entry of array to be the one you want as.

> Select your Device

There are multiple questions already existing on StackOverflow which you can refer to and to do the overriding , a generalized solution has been suggested.

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one).

Or the other way round, you can also [set the customized default position of spinner](http://codetheandroid.blogspot.in/2012/07/assigning-default-values-to-spinners.html),your way, using this snippet of code :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdap = (ArrayAdapter<String>) mySpinner.getAdapter();

int spinnerPosition = messgAdap.getPosition(theDefaultValue);

mySpinner.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
```

Answer (score 7):

you can use like,

```
final ArrayList<String> strDeviceArr = new ArrayList<>();
      strDeviceArr.add("Select device");
      strDeviceArr.add("Nexus X");
      strDeviceArr.add("Nexus XL");

      spnrDevice.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, R.layout
        .layout_spinner_textview, R.id.textView, strDeviceArr));

      spnrDevice.setSelection(0); //set default selection to 0

      spnrDevice.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
         @Override
         public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String valueSelected = strDeviceArr.get(position);
         }

         @Override
         public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

         }
      });
```

Comment: I tried this but I is not worked for me.I'm using dropdown

Comment: go through this link it will give you clear idea...http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/

Answer (score 3):

For selecting an item from the drop-down:
Just after setting adapter

```
spinner.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
spinner.setSelection(position);
//position is integer starting from 0 to n-1 (n is number of items in the list or array). This will set nth item as the selected and visible item to the user.
```

Comment: It should be `spinner.setSelection(position)` instead of `spinner.setSelected(position)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this sequence:

```
dropdown                = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.target_dropdown);
List<String> targetList = new ArrayList<>(targetSet);
targetList.add(0, "Select a device");
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
  this,
  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
  targetList
);
dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
dropdown.setSelection(0);
```

Answer (score -1):

Please find below code

```
 val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, gender_array)
            genderSpinner!!.adapter = arrayAdapter as SpinnerAdapter?
            **genderSpinner!!.setSelection(2)**
            genderSpinner!!.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                    select_gender = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
                }

                override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

                }
            }
```