# How to set initial text in spinner instead first item of json response

Tags: android, json, android-spinner

I am using json parsing in my app,i am getting country name from json,the issue is in my json response first country is "Andorra", but by default i want to display "Select Country",following is my json response and code,can any one help me with this??

```
[{"user_status":"1","country_id":"1","country":"Andorra"},{"user_status":"1","country_id":"2","country":"United Arab Emirates"},{"user_status":"1","country_id":"3","country":"Afghanistan"},{"user_status":"1","country_id":"4","country":"Antigua and Barbuda"},{"user_status":"1","country_id":"5","country":"Anguilla"},{"user_status":"1","country_id":"6","country":"Albania"},{"user_status":"1","country_id":"7","country":"Armenia"},{"user_status":"1","country_id":"8","country":"Angola"},]
```

MY CODE

```
class Logincity extends
            AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        private String test;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Registration.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_progress));
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(
                String... args) {
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
            // Making a request to url and getting response
            citydata = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(CITY_URL, ServiceHandler.GET);
            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    jsonObjcitys = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                    // state_list = jsonObj.getJSONArray(COUNTRY_LIST);
                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonObjcitys.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = jsonObjcitys.getJSONObject(i);
                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        //map.put(CITY_NAME, c.getString(CITY_NAME));

                        map.put(CITY_NAME, c.getString(CITY_NAME));
                        //  map.put(PRESET_TITLES, c.getString(PRESET_TITLES));
                        citydata.add(map);

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }
            return citydata;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            arrallcitiies = new String[citydata.size()];
            for (int index = 0; index < citydata.size(); index++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = citydata.get(index);
                arrallcitiies[index] = map.get(CITY_NAME);
            }
            // pass arrConuntry array to ArrayAdapter<String> constroctor :
            adapterallcities = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    Registration.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, arrallcitiies);
            spinrcountry.setAdapter(adapterallcities);

            spinrcountry.setPrompt("Select City");
            spinrcountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    cityspitems = spinrcountry.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    System.out.println("PresetEVent selected" + cityspitems);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                }
            });




        }
    }
```

Comment: try to do like this before adding json response to the list, HashMap<String, String> defaultmap = new HashMap<String, String>();  defaultmap.put("Select Country","Select Country");citydata.add(defaultmap);

Comment: @ajantha where can i add that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one

Comment: after this , citydata = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

Comment: @Jolly: take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23005376/1878151

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just you need add "Select Country" at first position of that array and `length=response items + 1`

```
    arrallcitiies = new String[citydata.size()+1];
    arrallcitiies[0]="Select Country"; //item at pos 0
    int j=1;
    for (int index = 0; index < citydata.size(); index++) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = citydata.get(index);
    arrallcitiies[j++] = map.get(CITY_NAME);
    }

    adapterallcities = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Registration.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, arrallcitiies);
    spinrcountry.setAdapter(adapterallcities);
```

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 250, size is 250

Comment: sorry I didnot notice that. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit

```
   // Making a request to url and getting response
            citydata = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(CITY_URL, ServiceHandler.GET);
```

to bellow:

```
// Making a request to url and getting response
            citydata = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            HashMap<String, String> map_select_country = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map_select_country.put("0","Select country");
            citydata.add(map_select_country); //add new this
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(CITY_URL, ServiceHandler.GET);
```

Comment: getting nullpointer here cityspitems = spinrcountry.getSelectedItem().toString();

Comment: uhm sorry @Jolly my answer only focus on how to add Selecet country string on top of spin

Comment: yes i also tried your answer it shows some weired output

{0,Select Country}

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

```
ArrayList<String> listcountry_id,listcountry;

listcountry_id=new ArrayList<String>();
listcountry=new ArrayList<String>();

 try {  
        JSONArray jarr=new JSONArray("your responce data here");

        for(int i=0;i<jarr.length();i++){

            JSONObject jobj=jarr.getJSONObject(i);
            listcountry_id.add(jobj.getString("country_id"));
            listcountry.add(jobj.getString("country"));              
        }       
    BindSpinnerData();      
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}

 spnData.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String ids = String.valueOf(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

private void BindSpinnerData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerLocation = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinneritem, listcountry);
    spinnerLocation.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinnerpopup);
    spnData.setAdapter(spinnerLocation); 
}
```

//spinneritem,spinnerpopup   are textview layout there you can set color of text and background of colors

Answer (score 0):

1. change below inside doInBackground()

   ```
   HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

   for (int i = 0; i < jsonObjcitys.length(); i++) {
       JSONObject c = jsonObjcitys.getJSONObject(i);
       // creating new HashMap

       // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
       //map.put(CITY_NAME, c.getString(CITY_NAME));

       map.put(CITY_NAME, c.getString(CITY_NAME));
       //  map.put(PRESET_TITLES, c.getString(PRESET_TITLES));
       citydata.add(map);

   }
   map.put("Select_City", "Select City");
   citydata.add(map);
   ```
2. change below inside onPostExecute()

   - After setting spinner adapter add below line.

     ```
     spinrcountry.setSelection(adapter.getCount());
     ```
3. you'll have to create a custom adapter

   ```
   public class HintAdapter extends ArrayAdapter < Objects > {


   public HintAdapter(Context theContext, int theLayoutResId, String[] objects) {
       super(theContext, theLayoutResId, R.id.text1, objects);
   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       // don't display last item. It is used as hint.
       int count = super.getCount();
       return count > 0 ? count - 1 : count;
   }
   }
   ```
4. change setAdapter line in onPostExecute() to below-

   ```
   adapterallcities = new HintAdapter(
               Registration.this,
               android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, arrallcitiies);
   ```

Above solution will display default "Select City" value and upon spinner selection it will only display list of City name and no default value.