# cannot resolve constructor ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,int,java.lang.String[],java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

Hi I am using an `ArrayAdapter` to display a default text in spinner and I don't understand the error

> cannot resolve constructor ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,int,java.lang.String[],java.lang.String,java.lang.String).

Can anyone tell me about this, please help me I don't know much about java coding.

```
 public class UneCon extends Fragment {

    private Spinner fromDetails, toDetails;
    private EditText fromInput, toInput;


    public static UneCon setArguments(int position) {
        UniqueConverter uniqueConverter = new UniqueConverter();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("position", position);
        uniqueConverter.setArguments(args);
        return uniqueConverter;
    }

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_uniquelayout, container, false);


        onInitVies(view);
        int position = getArguments().getInt("position");

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                setAdapter(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.temperatureform), "Celsius", "Fahrenheit");

                break;
            case 1:
                setAdapter(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.weightform), "Kilograms", "Grams");

                break;

 return view;

    }


    private void setAdapter(String[] spinnerItems, String fromDefaultText, String toDefaultText) {

        fromDetails.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, spinnerItems, fromDefaultText, toDefaultText));//here it getting error//
    }

    private void onInitVies(View view) {
        fromDetails = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.fromSpinner);
        toDetails = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.toSpinner);

        fromInput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.fromInput);
        toInput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.toInput);
    }
}
```

Comment: Google It. Here i found it :- http://coderzpassion.com/android-working-with-spinner/

Comment: You are using invalid constructor. See this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you want to do with `fromDefaultText` and `toDefaultText`. You don't need to pass that (unless you have specific use of it and using custom adapter). For now

Change

```
fromDetails.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, spinnerItems, fromDefaultText, toDefaultText));
```

to

```
fromDetails.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerItems));
```

Comment: I have two spinners so by using fromdefaultText and to, I'm setting default text to spinners

Comment: @sun You dont need to pass those two values to `ArrayAdapter`. You can pass them to `setSpinner` method and take any action on them but dont pass in `ArrayAdapter`. Just replace you code with mine and it would work.

Comment: Thank you @rohit then how can we pass default text than?

Comment: @sun See this post. It has various ways to do that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever seen the [Doc](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)?

There are 6 types of constructor in [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) class.
And there are 2 constructors having maximum parameter of 4. And you are passing 5 parameters currently..

**The 2 Constructors having max number of parameters are :**

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)
```

**And**

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)
```

We are not sure what are you currently trying to do now. I suggest you to initialize `ArrayAdapter` transforming your current initialization into the above one..

Comment: Thank you It helps me I don't know about it

Comment: how did you modified that ? what are your `fromDefaultText` and `toDefaultText` ?

Comment: They are for, to set default text to my spinners

Answer (score -1):

change `getContext()` to `getActivity()`

and following are four type of array adapter in android.

```
 ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource)
Constructor
    ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId)
Constructor
    ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects)
Constructor
    ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)
Constructor
    ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<T> objects)
Constructor
    ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)
Constructor
```

hope this will help you.