# First item of spinner to set to select one

Tags: android

```
ArrayAdapter<StringWithTag> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<StringWithTag>(RegisterActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countryList);
spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
mSpinnerCountry.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

Comment: Please add some description to the question.

Comment: @Faheem Ahmad try with my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38321179/3981656

Answer (score 2):

Create your `countryList` array with `Select One` element. like,

```
String[] countryList = new String[]{"Select One" ,"India" , "China" , "Japan"};
```

This may helps you

Comment: But this will take a an option "select one" in the drop down.

Comment: yeah, yes . any problem with this?

Comment: "select one"  should not be on drop down list.

Comment: refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one

Comment: if it's helpful means kindly mark as answer. so other can find answer easily.

Answer (score 1):

Add first item of the spinner as "Select One" and in onclick listener set the condition as mentioned below.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (position == 0)
            {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Select any one option",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if (position == 1)
            {
                // add you stuff
            }
            else {
                // add your stuff
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "Select One" as the first item in your list i.e. `countryList`