# Prompt in Spinner in Android isn't working

Tags: android, arrays, android-spinner, prompt

I was trying to set prompt in Spinner in android,over dynamically add data in spinner.Firstly, I have used **spinner.setPrompt(" Branch List ")** but couldn't set it in spinner. though my this line of code is wroking. But still didn't get it done.and then I used second method which is as follows:

I here by share my code of xml which is second method that I've used for setting prompt.

**MainActivity.xml**

```
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/branchSpinner"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:prompt="@string/Branch"
            />
```

**Stings.xml**

```
<string name="Branch">Branch</string>
```

Comment: Question is slimier to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **android:spinnerMode="dialog"** if u want to show prompt using spinner.

```
           <Spinner
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/branchSpinner"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            android:prompt="@string/Branch"
            />
```

Comment: But I don't want it as Dialog.I want If none item is selected then it will show the prompt text in my spinner which isn't visible in my arraylist added to spinner.

Comment: android:spinnerMode only works in dialog mode not in dropdown mode.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Akshay but I have followed different method bacuse what i want is couldn't acheived by this