# Clean way to set Spinner's initial text

Tags: android, spinner

I've googled the way to set initial text for spinner widget such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one) and elsewhere but I haven't found any solution that use less memory, less line of code. 
So, Is there any alternative way to do this "clean" ?

Comment: It is good practice and it is encouraged! I'm not the downvoter, but I think the downvote is motivated by the fact that you haven't created a "real" question. You should do that so other people could answer your question too, and because future readers might not even notice that you answered you own question & get confused.

Comment: @RonanBoiteau Edited the question, Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome! Also, you should define "clean". Is it less lines of code? Code that's easier to understand? Faster code? Code that uses less memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: one] -> 
[image: two]

The code:

```
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
    data.add("a");
    data.add("b");
    data.add("c");
    data.add("d");

    Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> stringListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data) {

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            if(position == getCount())
                return "Please Select One";
            else
                return super.getItem(position);
        }
    };
    stringListAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(stringListAdapter);
    spinner.setSelection(data.size());
```

The XML:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"/>
```