# Change spinner text without making a selection

Tags: android

Is there a way to set spinner text to a value that doesn't exist in the drop-down list ? Best case would be:

```
spinner.setText(value);
```

But spinner not allowing that.

Comment: You want to set hint to Spinner ?

Comment: Do you want to add new item in the spinner list?

Comment: Without adding new item to list and without hint

Comment: You need to create your own SpinnerAdapter and override getView method

Comment: [How to make an Android Spinner with initial text “Select One”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one)