# How can we keep the edit box by default empty, which displays the result of the spinner?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-spinner

```
 String[] categories = {"All", "Surgeon", "Pediatrician", "Cardiologist", "Dermatologist"};
        String[][] dca={
                {"Dr Chandiram","Dr Hamza","Dr Pervaiz","Dr Naeem","Dr Rajesh","Dr Sami"},
                {"Dr Chandiram","Dr Hamza",},
                {"Dr Pervaiz"},{"Dr Naeem","Dr Rajesh"},
                {"Dr Sami"}
                };
        ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,categories);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        drspin.setAdapter(aa);
        drspin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String a = drspin.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if(a.equals("All")){
                    ArrayAdapter myad = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,dca[0]);
                    drcat.setAdapter(myad);
                }else if(a.equals("Surgeon")){
                    ArrayAdapter myad = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,dca[1]);
                    drcat.setAdapter(myad);
                }else if(a.equals("Pediatrician")){
                    ArrayAdapter myad = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,dca[2]);
                    drcat.setAdapter(myad);
                }
                else if(a.equals("Cardiologist")){
                    ArrayAdapter myad = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,dca[3]);
                    drcat.setAdapter(myad);
                }
                else if(a.equals("Dermatologist")){
                    ArrayAdapter myad = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,dca[4]);
                    drcat.setAdapter(myad);
                }

//                sd.setText(a);
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
        drcat.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    sd.setText(drcat.getSelectedItem().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

**How can we keep the edit box by default empty, which displays the result of the spinner, when we click on any item of spinner then only it must show the result in the edit box else it must remain empty**

Comment: What is it showing by default?

Comment: the first value in the spinner @akhilnair

Comment: that's spinner default behavior.

Comment: @dinkar_kumar so there is no solution to my question?

Comment: Any reason you don't want a default selected option?

Comment: @dinkar_kumar yes the reason I want it to be empty by default is that I have connected it to firebase and I want it to show an error if any of the fields remain empty, but here the problem I am getting is that other fields remain empty still due to spinner having its value in it, it shows error and with that, it stores half info in the database which I don't want to happen.

Comment: I think you should check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26475701/14449761

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solution in your case can be as follows:

```
String[] categories = {"Select","All", "Surgeon", "Pediatrician", "Cardiologist", "Dermatologist"};


 drspin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String a = drspin.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if(a.equals("Select")){
                editText.setText("");
            } else if(a.equals("All")){
                ArrayAdapter myad = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,dca[0]);
                drcat.setAdapter(myad);
            }else if(a.equals("Surgeon")){
                ArrayAdapter myad = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,dca[1]);
                drcat.setAdapter(myad);
            }else if(a.equals("Pediatrician")){
                ArrayAdapter myad = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,dca[2]);
                drcat.setAdapter(myad);
            }
            else if(a.equals("Cardiologist")){
                ArrayAdapter myad = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,dca[3]);
                drcat.setAdapter(myad);
            }
            else if(a.equals("Dermatologist")){
                ArrayAdapter myad = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,dca[4]);
                drcat.setAdapter(myad);
            }

        }
```

Comment: @amnaa It would be great if you could also upvote it as it would help other developers having the same problem.